# Label Increment on Button Click with For Loop C#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, label, increment

I am trying to get a label to increase by 1 with each button click up to 5 then revert back to 1 and start again. However, I seem to be entering my for loop incorrectly. Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Very new to C#.

```
private void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int bet = 1;
    if (bet < 6)
    {
        for (int bet = 1; bet <= 6; bet++)
        {
            lblBet.Text = "" + bet;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblBet.ResetText();
    }
}
```

-The label text is defaulted to 1.

Thank you

Comment: No way to see your label changes its text. The updating of the label happens only after you exit from the event handler.

Comment: What's the purpose of for loop? The iteration is so fast, you won't see it visually.

Comment: no point for loop, just use a grobal variable start with 1, and every time user click the button, just add the variable with 1, or reset it if the value is 6,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the button is clicked, you change the value of the label, incrementing its current value.
This solution uses the [% Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

```
private void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentValue;
    // Tries to parse the text to an integer and puts the result in the currentValue variable
    if (int.TryParse(lblBet.Text, out currentValue))
    {
        // This equation assures that the value can't be greater that 5 and smaller than 1
        currentValue = (currentValue % 5) + 1;
        // Sets the new value to the label 
        lblBet.Text = currentValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

***Explaining the % operator***

"The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second"

So in this case the results will be:

```
int currentValue = 1;
int remainderCurrentValue = currentValue % 5; // Equals 1
int increasedCurrentValue = remainderCurrentValue + 1; // Equals 2
```

And when the current value is 5 this is going to happen:

```
int currentValue = 5;
int remainderCurrentValue = currentValue % 5; // Equals 0
int increasedCurrentValue = remainderCurrentValue + 1; // Equals 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the for loop. I overlooked that it wouldn't pause between each increment. This worked great, minus that it resets back to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @sploosh4snootch Yes, my bad! I wrote the wrong algorithm... but then I edited my answer and now should do the job

Comment: My apologies. I replied before refreshing to see your edits. Thanks again! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want:

```
int bet = 1;
bool increase=true;
private void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(increase){
      bet++;
      lblBet.Text = "" + bet;
   }
   else{
       bet--;
       lblBet.Text = "" + bet;
   }
   if(bet==5 || bet==1)
   {
       increase=!increase;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need the value of the label for your business logic - to place a bet. I think you should have a  private variable for it, increment it from the button onclick event, then copy it into the label textbox.

```
            private void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int bet = int.Parse(lblBet.Text);
                lblBet.Text = bet<5 ? ++bet : 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int bet = 1;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bet++;

        if (bet == 6)
            bet = 1;                

        lblBet.Text = bet.ToString();
    }
```

Bet variable needs to be declared outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
static int count=0;// Global Variable declare somewhere at the top 

protected void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;

            if (count > 6)
            {
                lblBet.Text = count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a for loop. Initialize bet outside of button click:

```
int bet = 1;
private void bttnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


   if (bet <= 6)
   {
       this.bet++;
       lblBet.Text = bet.toString();
   }

}
```